# How do you Bulk Print multiple Visual elements as one task?

Tags: c#, wpf, object, printing

I have multiple `UserControl` where each represent a Page, but I don't know how to print them, because until now I'm only able to print a single `UserControl`

Here is how I print a single `UserControl`:

```
PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
     printDlg.PrintVisual((UserControl)myUserControl, "optionalname");
}
```

How do you print multiple objects from type `Visual` in one task?

Comment: Just a thought. Can you put all visuals inside a paren control (i.e. Grid) and print that control?

Comment: @keftmedei but than i will get 1 Page which contains all UserControls as result and not 1 page per `UserControl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research, I found following [Blog](http://marktinderholt.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/multi-page-document-generation-with-xps-part-i-the-problem/) where someone tried to achieve the same thing with no luck because he has some copy&past typos. I fixed his typos and it works very well.

**here an working sample:**

```
using System;
using System.Printing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Xps;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<UIElement> UC = new List<UIElement>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var uc = new UserControl
            {
                Background = Brushes.Red,
                Content = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "Box:" + i,
                    Margin = new Thickness(12),
                    Background = Brushes.Orange
                }
            };
            UC.Add(uc);
        }

        var pDialog = new PrintDialog();

        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var xpsDocWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pDialog.PrintQueue);
            PrintUIElements(xpsDocWriter, UC);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used the XpsDocumentWriter to write a FixedDocumentSequence which contains the UIElements as single pages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xpsWriter"></param>
    /// <param name="uiElements"></param>
    private void PrintUIElements(XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter, List<UIElement> uiElements)
    {
        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = new FixedDocumentSequence();

        foreach (UIElement element in uiElements)
        {
            (fixedDocSeq as IAddChild).AddChild(toDocumentReference(element));

        }

        // write the FixedDocumentSequence as an XPS Document
        xpsWriter.Write(fixedDocSeq);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// encapsulater for a UIElement in an DocumentReference
    /// DocumentReference(FixedDocument(PageContent(FixedPage(UIElement))))
    /// to simplify the print of multiple pages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uiElement">the UIElement which</param>
    /// <returns>creates a DocumentReference</returns>
    private DocumentReference toDocumentReference(UIElement uiElement)
    {
        if (uiElement == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("the UIElement has to be not null");

        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        DocumentReference docRef = new DocumentReference();

        #region Step1

        // add the UIElement object the FixedPage
        fixedPage.Children.Add(uiElement);

        #endregion

        #region Step2

        // add the FixedPage to the PageContent collection
        pageContent.BeginInit();
        ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
        pageContent.EndInit();

        #endregion

        #region Step 3

        // add the PageContent to the FixedDocument collection
        ((IAddChild)fixedDoc).AddChild(pageContent);

        #endregion

        #region Step 4

        // add the FixedDocument to the document reference collection
        docRef.BeginInit();
        docRef.SetDocument(fixedDoc);
        docRef.EndInit();

        #endregion

        return docRef;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The above code contains a binding bug for the first page, but I was able to fix it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Used the XpsDocumentWriter to write a FixedDocument which get created and contains the UIElements as single pages
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xpsWriter">XpsDocumentWriter</param>
/// <param name="uiElements">List of UIElement</param>
private void PrintUIElements(XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter, List<UIElement> uiElements)
{
    var fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();

    foreach (UIElement element in uiElements)
    {
        var fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        var pageContent = new PageContent();

        // add the UIElement object the FixedPage
        fixedPage.Children.Add(element);

        // add the FixedPage object the PageContent
        pageContent.Child = fixedPage;

        // add the PageContent object the FixedDocument
        fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
    }

    xpsWriter.Write(fixedDoc);
}
```

Comment: The blog link in the post is dead. The blog has moved here:   https://ipushrocks.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/multi-page-document-generation-with-xps-part-i-the-problem/

Comment: You need to build with .NET 4 or later, as if you use .NET 3.5 the build fails because  pageContent.Child  is read-only.